# How do I remove myself from a company page on careers?

Tags: support, jobs, company-page

I have switched to a different company a few months ago, but my previous company still has me listed as an employee under "who you'll work with" on their careers company page.

How can I remove myself from that listing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Currently the owner of the Company Page has to remove you from the page. The fact that it is not under the user's control as well is definitely a bug and we'll work on enabling that for the user as well as the company.</strike>

In the meantime, if you let me know what company page it is I can remove you.

**EDIT** Seems as though I was wrong. The option is on your privacy page:

[image]

Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: Where do I find that page today?

Comment: For anyone looking for this, (today) it's on the Developer Story page - right side "update privacy". For me the link is https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences/25124#privacy but I guess for others the number is different :-)